# Flutter Bottom Navigation Bar Design And Indicator

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I'm trying to make the bottom navbar as in the picture, but I'm having difficulty adjusting the spacing between the items. I used an image instead of an icon. And I gave the images width and height values. But when I wanted to reduce their whitespace, I couldn't achieve it. Can you help me with this?

IMAGE:

[image]

MY CODE:

```
bottomNavigationBar: !navBarHide
              ? SafeArea(
                  child: BottomNavigationBar(
                      onTap: (index) {
                        debugPrint(controller.tabIndex.toString());
                        controller.tabChange(index);
                        controller.update();
                        if (index == 0) {
                          Get.offAndToNamed('dashboard');
                        } else if (index == 1) {
                          Get.offAndToNamed('blank');
                        } else if (index == 2) {
                          Get.offAndToNamed('home');
                        } else if (index == 3) {
                          Get.offAndToNamed('blank');
                        } else if (index == 4) {
                          Get.offAndToNamed('menu');
                        }
                      },
                      unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 0),
                      unselectedFontSize: 0,
                      unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
                        size: Get.width > 390 ? 24.sp : 24.sp,
                      ),
                      selectedFontSize: 0,
                      selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
                        size: Get.width > 390 ? 24.sm : 24.sm,
                      ),
                      selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 0),
                      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                      landscapeLayout:
                          BottomNavigationBarLandscapeLayout.spread,
                      unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
                      selectedItemColor: Colors.orange,
                      showSelectedLabels: false,
                      showUnselectedLabels: false,
                      currentIndex: controller.tabIndex,
                      // tamamdır
                      items: [
                        _bottomNavbarItem(
                          AppAssets.card_icon,
                          '',
                        ),
                        _bottomNavbarItem(
                          AppAssets.key_icon,
                          '',
                        ),
                        _bottomNavbarItem(
                          AppAssets.home_icon,
                          '',
                        ),
                        _bottomNavbarItem(
                          AppAssets.doc_icon,
                          '',
                        ),
                        _bottomNavbarItem(
                          AppAssets.menu_icon,
                          '',
                        ),
                      ]),
                )
              : null,
//ITEMSMETHOD
  _bottomNavbarItem(String assetName, String label) {
return BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Image.asset(
    assetName,
    width: 25.w,
    height: 22.h,
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
  ),
  activeIcon: Container(
    width: 25.w,
    height: 22.h,
    child: Image.asset(assetName),
  ),
  label: label,
);
} }
```

MY OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Not shure whate you want? You want bigger icons to reduce space between icons?

Answer (score 1):

Easy way of doing this using `Stack`

```dart
AnimatedPositioned(
      bottom: 0,
      left: constraints.maxWidth / 3 * (_selectedIndex) + //(totalTab=3) space of current index
          (constraints.maxWidth / 6) - // (totalTab*2=6) minimize the half of tab width  
          30, // minimize the width of dash
```

[image]

Play with this widget

```dart
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Stack(
          children: [
            BottomNavigationBar(
              showSelectedLabels: false,
              showUnselectedLabels: false,
              items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  label: 'Home',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.business),
                  label: 'Business',
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.school),
                  label: 'School',
                ),
              ],
              currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
              selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
              onTap: _onItemTapped,
            ),
            AnimatedPositioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: constraints.maxWidth /
                      3 *
                      (_selectedIndex) + //space of current index
                  (constraints.maxWidth / 6) - // minimize the half of it
                  30, // minimize the width of dash
              child: Container(
                width: 60,
                height: 8,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(12),
                    )),
              ),
              duration: const Duration(
                milliseconds: 100,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```